# Python, pandas find the length of each row based on a stop criteria

Tags: python, pandas, find

I have a dataset where the -1 means the point where I need to stop reading.
For example the dataset looks like that:

```py
          0   1   2    3    4  5
0       58  68  58   59   -1 -1
1       59  69  59   -1   -1 -1
2       93  94  93   33   -1 -1
3       58  59  58   68   -1 -1
4       92  94  92   33   -1 -1
```

where the -1 at column 4 means stop reading elements.

More precisely, I want to return the length per row  (how many elements exist until -1 appears), for all rows.

So first row has length of 4 (4 elements until the -1). Row two has length 3. Row three has length 4 and so on.

For doing that I think I need in pandas perhaps a way to get per row the index where the first -1 occurs.

How I can do something like that in a nice way in pandas (so avoid the long for loop option?)

I would like to thank you in advance for your help.
Regards
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach involves subtracting sum of `True` from the `df.shape[1]` :

```
df.assign(new=df.shape[1]-df.eq(-1).sum(axis=1))
```

---

```
    0   1   2   3  4  5  new
0  58  68  58  59 -1 -1    4
1  59  69  59  -1 -1 -1    3
2  93  94  93  33 -1 -1    4
3  58  59  58  68 -1 -1    4
4  92  94  92  33 -1 -1    4
```

Answer (score 2):

### `numpy.argmax`

You can compare DataFrame values to -1, then use `numpy.argmax` to get the number of non-zero values per row.

```
(df.values == -1).argmax(axis=1)
# array([4, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

Assigning this back,

```
df['num_vals'] = (df.values == -1).argmax(axis=1))
df

    0   1   2   3  4  5  num_vals
0  58  68  58  59 -1 -1         4
1  59  69  59  -1 -1 -1         3
2  93  94  93  33 -1 -1         4
3  58  59  58  68 -1 -1         4
4  92  94  92  33 -1 -1         4
```

This works by always returning the column index of the first -1 found in each row, so is more general.

---

### `.cumsum(axis=1)` + `.max(axis=1)`

```
df['num_vals'] = (df != -1).cumsum(axis=1).max(axis=1)
df

    0   1   2   3  4  5  num_vals
0  58  68  58  59 -1 -1         4
1  59  69  59  -1 -1 -1         3
2  93  94  93  33 -1 -1         4
3  58  59  58  68 -1 -1         4
4  92  94  92  33 -1 -1         4
```

This assumes your -1 values are at the end of their respective rows always.